# Hold Timeout in Twilio Flex - Flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex, twilio-taskrouter

Noob to Twilio Flex. Have built a 3 language voice IVR. Everything is working as expected except how to manage callers when there are no agents available or if an agent doesn't answer in a timely manor.

I have tried setting the timeout on the "send to Flex" widget, the TaskRouter Wrokflow, and the TaskQueues, but to no avail.

Ideally I would want them to hear the hold music for a predetermined time then be sent to a "unavailable" message if no one answers or if no agents are available.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

The element in question is "English_SendCallToAgent"

`{
      "name": "English_SendCallToAgent",
      "type": "SendToFlex",
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": -860,
          "y": 2030
        },
        "workflow": "WW.................................",
        "channel": "TC.................................",
        "attributes": "{ \"type\": \"inbound\", \"name\": \"{{trigger.call.From}}\",\"call_sid\": \"{{trigger.call.sid}}\"}",
        "timeout": 5,
        "priority": null,
        "waitUrl": "https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH.................................",
        "waitUrlMethod": null
      },
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "callComplete",
          "conditions": [],
          "next": null,
          "uuid": "e1................................."
        },
        {
          "event": "failedToEnqueue",
          "conditions": [],
          "next": "FF.................................",
          "uuid": "25................................."
        },
        {
          "event": "callFailure",
          "conditions": [],
          "next": null,
          "uuid": "8c................................."
        }
      ],
      "sid": "FF................................."
    },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a Twilio Help Center article that provides some insights here.

[Implementing Voicemail with Twilio Flex, TaskRouter, and WFO](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021082934-Implementing-Voicemail-with-Twilio-Flex-TaskRouter-and-WFO)

> This guide walks you through creating a special voicemail-specific
>   TaskRouter queue with no agents, and a workflow to send tasks to this
>   queue after they've waited for 30 seconds.

Comment: This is a very helpful start. I modified it to just play a message then drop the call. 

I cannot get the filter and timout to work properly. It either never get routed to the "Voicemail" queue or it gets routed directly to the vm queue.

Comment: The workflow rules in question is as follows
`{
  "task_routing": {
    "filters": [
      {
        "expression": "1==1",
        "targets": [
          {
            "queue": "WQ5a........................................................",  <<<<Actual Agent Queue
            "timeout": 10
          },
          {
            "queue": "WQd5........................................................",<<<<Voicemail Queue
            "timeout": 30
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "default_filter": {
      "queue": "WQ5a40898198c89dc70b996aee5d2d2149"
    }
  }
}`